# MSBuild trying to use .NET core targets for .NET Framework project

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core

I have .NET 4.6 web application, and it builds fine on my machine - both from Visual Studio and MSBuild command line. On different machine (build agent, with Visual Studio installed), I get build errors like this:

```
[restore] C:\blabla\myapp.csproj(430,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

In csproj file, the import looks like this

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

So it seems that `VSToolsPath` is set to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0` for some reason. It seems to me, like MSBuild is trying to use .NET Core "tools". What can be reason for this and how to fix it?

EDIT: Adding build command (bat file):

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin";%PATH%

msbuild "mysolution.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:TargetProfile="ProdCloud"
```

Comment: What command line call was used to invoke the build?

Comment: @MartinUllrich good point, I have edited the question